# Creating a 3D mushroom cloud

Tags: 3d, particles, graphic-effects

Hi I am trying to create a mushroom cloud animation for my strategy game. Something like [this](http://images.ea.com/eagames/official/cc_generals_redesign/screenshots/pc/set2/scrn_5.jpg). I have been looking at info for creating explosions in general, and the way to go seems to be using 2D sprites and billboarding. However, I don't think this will work in my case as mushroom clouds have a specific orientation, and I am using an arcball camera as my game takes place on a globe.

I've thought about using some kind of particle system, but it seems pretty complicated to make as opposed to using a sprite sheet.

What would be the best way to create a nice looking mushroom cloud?

Comment: I would start by studying how it should look like. You can use fluid dynamics and CML. Ofcourse you probably wont be running physic simulation at runtime, but it can give you a good idea how to animate your particle system correctly. Google give for example [this](http://www.iis.sinica.edu.tw/page/jise/2004/200403_02.pdf) for vulcano clouds, it cant be too difficult to modify it to suit your needs.

Comment: Needs more detail. Are you set on a procedural solution using particles or are you open to precomputation or manually 3D-modeling the thing?

Comment: @Anko I'm open to either. I imagine modeling it is easier, however I'm guessing I would need to find an artist (which I'm not against).

Answer (score 0):

If you have to model that kind of effect in a 3d space such as on a planetoid you are going to need the system to respond to different camera angles and a sprite sheet just isn't going to work unless you pin two of the axis's which your description indicates isn't feasible.

Depending on the game engine you are using, a particle system is going to be the easiest method. You might break it down into three parts:
1) The blast radius along the explosion plane
2) The vertical tower of smoke connecting the hat to the explosion origin
3) The cap billowing and drifting up into the vertical axis

If you are using a tool like Unity3d you can play with each independent piece until it looks right. Then put them under one game object. Here is a quick search in the asset store you find similar effects free and already completed like at http://tinyurl.com/pgwsofa which could at least give you more ideas.